# Ubuntu 14.04 Kernel Update 3.13.0-30.55 made my Laptop CPU gets overheated

Tags: 14.04, kernel, cpu, overheating

I just received an update to the linux kernel of Ubuntu 14.04 from 3.13.0-30.54 to 3.13.0-30.55. After I upgrade it the CPU on my laptop is around 70 to 80 Degree Celsius. while on the previous kernel is about 55-65 Degree Celsius, and never reach about 75 Degree, except on some situation like running a Virtual Machine.

I don't know what caused this but I have to downgrade it to the previous 3.13.0-30.54 to prevent overheating on continual use.

Hope there is a new kernel update that fixes this.

Screenshot of the synaptic to show the version of the kernel will be posted later.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to downgrade the kernel properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't have synaptic  package manager .
 install synaptic package manager.

```
$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

open it search in the quick filter for

```
linux-image
```

right click the kernel that you are wanting to keep '3.13.0-30.54'
mark for upgrade
right click on the kernel that you want to remove '3.13.0-30.54'
mark for removale & lock it by clicking in the menu package => lock version => uncheck auto install

then click on apply

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

pic : [image: finding the kernel version]